# running msiexec with parameters on remote machine

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, invoke, powershell-remoting

I am trying to run msiexec.exe with powershell on remote machine using Invoke-Command but it is not passing arguments into installer. I tried in several ways, my code looks like this:

```
$params = @(
  $DataPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\path'
  $Type = "Dev"
  $DbUser="User"
  $DbPassword="password"
  $sqlServerUser= "user"
  $sqlServerPassword="password"
  $QMName="name"
  $QMAddress="address"
  $QMPort="1212"
  $MqUser="user"
  $MqPassword="password"
  $SERVER_TYPE="Dev" 
  $RUNTIME_SQL_AUTH_TYPE="WINDOWS_AUTH" 
  $SQL_AUTH_TYPE="WINDOWS_AUTH"
  $RECYCLING_TIME="03:00"
)

$InstallerPath = "$Path.msi"

$scriptInstallServer = 
{
    (Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i $Using:InstallerPath /qn /norestart $Using:params" -Wait -Passthru).WaitForExit()
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock $scriptInstallServer
```

AND

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {msiexec /i $Using:serverInstallerPath $Using:params /passive}
```

I have tried:
[Install MSI on remote host using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67224518/install-msi-on-remote-host-using-powershell)

[Installing an MSI file on a remote machine with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070671/installing-an-msi-file-on-a-remote-machine-with-powershell)

[Install .msi remotely using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911768/install-msi-remotely-using-powershell)

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I would try splatting maybe (try a hashtable): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @mklement0 I have tried but stackoverflow does not see my new lines after each argument

Comment: @shadow2020 thanks for a reply.. I have tried but still the same problem. Invoke-Command does not take the args

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to create an array won't work as intended:

> `$params = @(`
>   `$DataPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\path'`
>   `$Type = "Dev"`
>   `# ...`
> `)`

This is the same as `$params = @()`, i.e. creating an *empty* array, and creating *individual variables* named `$DataPath`, `$Type`, ...; that is, your use of `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) encloses *variable assignments*, which themselves *output nothing*, so that the resulting array is empty.

If the intent is to define `$params` as an array of CLI arguments for `msiexec`, specifically as `PROPNAME=PROPVALUE` arguments, you need to use this instead:

```bash
$params = @(
  'DataPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\path"'
  'Type=Dev'
  # ...
)
```

Note the use of literal property names, the need to quote each argument (line) as whole, the absence of whitespace around `=`, and the *embedded, selective `"..."` quoting* for property values that contain spaces.

Then you should be able to call as follows:

```bash
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
  # cmd /c invokes msiexec *synchronously*
  # Passing the msiexec command line inside "..." overall ensures
  # that the selective value quoting is passed through as such.
  cmd /c "msiexec /qn /norestart /i `"$using:installerPath`" $using:params"
  # $LASTEXITCODE now contains msiexec's exit code.
}
```

Comment: that helped, so thanks for an answer. But now I have another issue. In my script I am copying quite large file, it takes 6 mins to copy and in that time I can't run another script because powershell is working. Is there any way to execute this script with different arguments in parallel? I read about creating jobs in powershell as scriptblocks but I need to run whole script for example for 5 different computers